# Character \ appearing before ' after saving a settings page

Tags: options, text, esc-textarea

It's a strange issue and I've seen it happen with plugins, however I don't know how to fix it. Maybe just a PHP issue?

Anyhow, I have a settings/options page with several text areas. Upon saving, a "\" appears before each apostrophe. Each time it's saved, an additional back-slash appears.

I'm not sure what code would be helpful to look at for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a PHP issue.  The character `'` is being escaped so that it can be safely in various places, not least of which is the database.  That's why your `'` look like `\'`.

You can use PHP's [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/stripslashes) function to clean it up, or (if it's an array you need to clean up) WordPress's [`stripslashes_deep()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep) function.